# Calling a class method from another class method in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm confused why this code won't work.  For `room_instance = self.startRoom()` I get the error:

```
'str' object is not callable.
```

**My code:**

```
class Corridor:
    def enter(self):
        print "Yureka. First Room!"

class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self, startRoom):
        self.startRoom = startRoom   #sets the startRoom to 'Corridor' for the eng instance
    def room_change(self):
        room_instance = self.startRoom()
        room_instance.enter()

eng = Engine('Corridor')
eng.room_change()
```

Comment: In your example, the methods defined are instance methods, not class methods. So, I think the title of this question should be updated to reflect that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use `eng = Engine('Corridor')` you pass `'Corridor'` as a string. To access class Corridor you should use `globals()['Corridor']`

```
class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self, startRoom):
        self.startRoom = globals()[startRoom]   #sets the startRoom to 'Corridor' for the eng instance

    def room_change(self):
        room_instance = self.startRoom()
        room_instance.enter()
```

But actually it's a rather fragile construction because `Corridor` may be defined in other module etc. So I would propose the following:

```
class Corridor:
    def enter(self):
        print "Yureka. First Room!"

class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self, startRoom):
        self.startRoom = startRoom   #sets the startRoom to 'Corridor' for the eng instance
    def room_change(self):
        room_instance = self.startRoom()
        room_instance.enter()

eng = Engine(Corridor) # Here you refer to _class_ Corridor and may refer to any class in any module
eng.room_change()
```