# Why is this condition in the if statement ignored?

Tags: python, class

This is the error I receive:

```
   >>> m.ask('please vend')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents", line 196, in ask
    getattr(self, 'vend')
AttributeError: 'MissManners' object has no attribute 'vend'
```

The `VendingMachine` class works fine but `MissManners` class doesn't. I don't know why.

```
class VendingMachine:
    """A vending machine that vends some product for some price.

    >>> v = VendingMachine('candy', 10)
    >>> v.vend()
    'Machine is out of stock.'
    >>> v.restock(2)
    'Current candy stock: 2'
    >>> v.vend()
    'You must deposit $10 more.'
    >>> v.deposit(7)
    'Current balance: $7'
    >>> v.vend()
    'You must deposit $3 more.'
    >>> v.deposit(5)
    'Current balance: $12'
    >>> v.vend()
    'Here is your candy and $2 change.'
    >>> v.deposit(10)
    'Current balance: $10'
    >>> v.vend()
    'Here is your candy.'
    >>> v.deposit(15)
    'Machine is out of stock. Here is your $15.'

    >>> w = VendingMachine('soda', 2)
    >>> w.restock(3)
    'Current soda stock: 3'
    >>> w.deposit(2)
    'Current balance: $2'
    >>> w.vend()
    'Here is your soda.'
    """
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
    def __init__(self, product, price):
        self.itemName = product
        self.cost = price
        self.stock = 0
        self.balance = 0
    def vend(self):
        if self.stock == 0:
            print(" 'Machine is out of stock.' ")
        elif self.balance < self.cost:
            print(" 'You must deposit $" + str(self.cost - self.balance) + " more.'")
        elif self.cost < self.balance:
            print(" 'Here is your " + self.itemName + " and $" + str(self.balance - self.cost) + " change.'")
            self.balance = 0
            self.stock -= 1
        else:
            self.balance -= self.cost
            self.stock -= 1
            print("'Here is your " + self.itemName +  ".'")
    def restock(self, amount):
        self.stock += amount
        print("'Current " + self.itemName + " stock: " + str(self.stock) + "'")
    def deposit(self, amount):
        if self.stock == 0:
            print("'Machine is out of stock. Here is your $" + str(amount) + ".'")
        else:
            self.balance += amount
            print("'Current balance: $" + str(self.balance) + "'")

class MissManners:
    """A container class that only forward messages that say please.

    >>> v = VendingMachine('teaspoon', 10)
    >>> v.restock(2)
    'Current teaspoon stock: 2'

    >>> m = MissManners(v)
    >>> m.ask('vend')
    'You must learn to say please first.'
    >>> m.ask('please vend')
    'You must deposit $10 more.'
    >>> m.ask('please deposit', 20)
    'Current balance: $20'
    >>> m.ask('now will you vend?')
    'You must learn to say please first.'
    >>> m.ask('please hand over a teaspoon')
    'Thanks for asking, but I know not how to hand over a teaspoon.'
    >>> m.ask('please vend')
    'Here is your teaspoon and $10 change.'"""
        def __init__(self, *args):
            self.ask

        def ask(self, *args):
            result = ''
            for arg in args:
                if type(arg) == str:
                    result += arg
                elif type(arg) == int:
                    balance = arg
            if 'please' in result:
                if 'deposit' in result:
                    self.deposit(balance)
                elif 'vend' in result:
                    self.vend()
            else:
                return 'You must learn to say please first.'
```

Comment: You think a variable has something in it, but your program thinks not. Its a good time to print that variable to see if it has what you think it has.

Comment: Don't edit your post to indicate that your problem is solved, instead please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. If you feel that the code should not be seen by others, please flag the post as "other" and explain the situation. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a `print result` before the if statement you'll get a hint as that why this is happening as it will output `['p', 'l', 'e', 'a', 's', 'e', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'p']` (assuming you called it with `('please', 'help)`. Remember this as print statements are a quick way of debugging problems of this nature (usually my go to before more extensive testing)

The reason for this is the use of the += operator (`result += arg`) - switch this to an [append method](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) (`result.append(arg)`) and it should work.

For your second question check out [Calling a Class Method From Another Class Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208274/calling-a-class-method-from-another-class-method-in-python-2-7) - as that provides a clean way of doing what you are trying to do with VendingMachine

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by JGreenwell, the reason why you get that is because your result is a list. Thus it collects all the characters to form a list:

```
['p', 'l', 'e', 'a', 's', 'e']
```

Instead of string 'please'. Here I present an alternative way to fix it: initialize your result as string:

```
result = ''
```

This way you will get the result you want

Comment: Thanks a lot! But why would this make it different? Aren't strings just lists?

Comment: It did work with your suggestion though! I just don't understand why

Comment: No, string is not list... I think JGreenwell has made a demonstration on that. List can contain anything from list, char, number, etc. But what you want is a string. Thus you should declare as string: result =''

Comment: Okay thank you! I don't really understand the concept of classes all too well and just ran into another error. Could I post it up there because I feel like I can't describe it well.

Comment: Just posted up and sorry for its length. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @AryatheCat also, if you have another question, please post a new question. To avoid confusion, the community here encourages to put up one question at time.